# How to set Title of Tab with MVVMCross 6.2?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, tabs, mvvmcross, android-appcompat

I'm trying to figure out how to properly set the localized string as Tab Title (or dynamically change the Tab Title) with MVVMCross 6.2+ in Xamarin Android.
How should I set the title of the tab in the simple example app?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is the simple example app:

## MvvmCrossTabs.Core

### HomeViewModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MvvmCross.Commands;
using MvvmCross.Logging;
using MvvmCross.Navigation;
using MvvmCross.ViewModels;

namespace MvvmCrossTabs.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class HomeViewModel : MvxNavigationViewModel
    {
        public IMvxAsyncCommand ShowInitialViewModelsCommand { get; private set; }

        public HomeViewModel(IMvxLogProvider logProvider, IMvxNavigationService navigationService) : base(logProvider, navigationService)
        {
            ShowInitialViewModelsCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(ShowInitialViewModels);
        }

        private async Task ShowInitialViewModels()
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(new List<Task>
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate<Tab1ViewModel>(),
                NavigationService.Navigate<Tab2ViewModel>(),
                NavigationService.Navigate<Tab3ViewModel>()
            });
        }
    }
}
```

### Tab1ViewModel.cs (Tab2ViewModel.cs, Tab3ViewModel.cs)

```
using MvvmCross.Logging;
using MvvmCross.Navigation;
using MvvmCross.ViewModels;

namespace MvvmCrossTabs.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class Tab1ViewModel : MvxNavigationViewModel
    {
        public Tab1ViewModel(IMvxLogProvider logProvider, IMvxNavigationService navigationService) : base(logProvider, navigationService)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

### App.cs

```
using MvvmCross.IoC;
using MvvmCross.ViewModels;
using MvvmCrossTabs.Core.ViewModels;

namespace MvvmCrossTabs.Core
{
    public class App : MvxApplication
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            CreatableTypes()
                .EndingWith("Service")
                .AsInterfaces()
                .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

            RegisterAppStart<HomeViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

## MvvmCrossTabs.Android

### MainApplication.cs

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat;
using MvvmCrossTabs.Core;

namespace MvvmCrossTabs.Android
{
    [Application]
    public class MainApplication : MvxAppCompatApplication<MvxAppCompatSetup<App>, App>
    {
        public MainApplication() : base() { }

        public MainApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) { }
    }
}
```

### home.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/maincontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### tab1.axml (tab2.axml, tab3.axml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

### styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

### HomeView.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat;
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Presenters.Attributes;
using MvvmCrossTabs.Core.ViewModels;

namespace MvvmCrossTabs.Android
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask, Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    [MvxActivityPresentation]
    public class HomeView : MvxAppCompatActivity<HomeViewModel>
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.home);

            // Replaces Action Bar with new Toolbar.
            var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            ViewModel.ShowInitialViewModelsCommand.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

### Tab1View.cs (Tab2View.cs, Tab3View.cs)

```
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4;
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Binding.BindingContext;
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Presenters.Attributes;
using MvvmCrossTabs.Core.ViewModels;

namespace MvvmCrossTabs.Android.Views
{
    [MvxTabLayoutPresentation(TabLayoutResourceId = Resource.Id.tabs, ViewPagerResourceId = Resource.Id.viewpager, Title = "Tab 1", ActivityHostViewModelType = typeof(HomeViewModel))]
    [Register(nameof(Tab1View))]
    public class Tab1View : MvxFragment<Tab1ViewModel>
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.tab1, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your tabs are created using the `ShowInitialViewModelsCommand`, the built-in presenter creates a list of `MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo` objects, passing in the Title value from the attributes. You can see that happening in the [ShowViewPagerFragment](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/32f19061313f3764289f498a153126561ff67b22/MvvmCross.Android.Support/V7.AppCompat/MvxAppCompatViewPresenter.cs#L395) method in the MvvmCross source code.

The list of `MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo` objects is then passed into the `MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter` that is created for the ViewPager. You can see that happening [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/32f19061313f3764289f498a153126561ff67b22/MvvmCross.Android.Support/V7.AppCompat/MvxAppCompatViewPresenter.cs#L465)

`MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter` inherits from the `MvxFragmentPagerAdapter` class. Inside the `MvxFragmentPagerAdapter` class is finally where the Title you provided is actually used. You can see it being used in the `GetPageTitleFormatted` method [here](https://github.com/martijn00/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/blob/8d5c8f5a8e7b43732f58e2dfb7c5ca4cc21158b0/MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Fragment/MvxFragmentPagerAdapter.cs#L59)

**So in order to change the Title at runtime, you could do the following:**

Subclass the default presenter and override the `ShowViewPagerFragment` method (it is marked virtual) and provide the correct localized title string instead of the one defined in the attribute

Here is an example of how to accomplish this:

**1.) Create a custom presenter and override `ShowViewPagerFragment`**

```
public class LocalizedTabPresenter : MvxAppCompatViewPresenter
{
    public LocalizedTabPresenter(IEnumerable<Assembly> androidViewAssemblies) : base(androidViewAssemblies)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<bool> ShowViewPagerFragment(Type view, MvxViewPagerFragmentPresentationAttribute attribute, MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        if (attribute.ViewModelType == typeof(Tab1ViewModel)) { 
            attribute.Title = "My Localized Title for Tab 1"
        }

        return base.ShowViewPagerFragment(view, attribute, request);
    }
}
```

**2.) In your `Setup.cs` class, let MvvmCross know to use the custom presenter instead**

```
protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
{
    return new LocalizedTabPresenter(AndroidViewAssemblies);
}
```

**Note:**

- This will only work if you need to **set the title only once** when the
  app launches and is setting up the tabs for the first time.

If you are in a situation where the Title can change multiple times while the app is running, you need to subclass `MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter` and override the `GetPageTitleFormatted` method and provide a more custom implementation that fits your use case.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was hoping for some easy solution (like statically defined localized resource - not working with MVVMCross), but this looks like something complicated. Let's say that for now I will be happy with the solution number one. Can you provide me with the example, please? I'm just starting with Xamarin and MVVMCross, so it is not that clear to me.

Comment: @Hubo - Added an example of how you would go about with implementing approach 1.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works perfectly. (I'm still a bit lost in understanding the MVVMCross Presenter.) I would like you to check my another problem which comes with my simple example app: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55103059/tabs-with-mvvmcross-6-2

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution would be to use the `IMvxOverridePresentationAttribute` interface.

This way you can change these values at runtime from the fragment itself.

To do it, simply implement `IMvxOverridePresentationAttribute` in your tab fragment, and then return something like this:

```
 public MvxBasePresentationAttribute PresentationAttribute(MvxViewModelRequest request)
 {
      return new MvxTabLayoutPresentationAttribute(title: _("Results"), viewPagerResourceId: Resource.Id.viewPager, tabLayoutResourceId: Resource.Id.tab_layout, fragmentHostViewType: typeof(HostFragment));
 }
```

I like this approach because I don't need to change anything at app level and I have all the code related to the fragment contained in that fragment specifically.

I've been using this and it has been working perfectly.

**Be aware that `this.ViewModel` property will be null during `PresentationAttribute`**

If you want a more detailed explanation on how it works, have a look at [this](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/xamarin.forms/xamarin-forms-view-presenter#override-a-presentation-attribute-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like that:

```
        if (fragments == null || fragments.Count == 0)
        {
            _firstFragment= (YourFragmentType)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(YourFragmentType));
            _firstFragment.ViewModel = YourVM;

            _secondFragment= (YourFragmentType)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(YourFragmentType));
            _secondFragment.ViewModel = YourVM;

            _thridFragment= (YourFragmentType)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(YourFragmentType));
            _thridFragment.ViewModel = YourVM;

            // Strings from RESX Localization
            fragments = new Dictionary<string, Fragment>
            {
                { Strings.first_localized_string, _firstFragment},
                { Strings.second_localized_string, _secondFragment},
                { Strings.thrid_localized_string, _thridFragment}
            };
        }

        viewPager = View.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);

        adapter = new TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(ChildFragmentManager, fragments);
        viewPager.Adapter = adapter;

        var tabLayout = View.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);
        tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Your adapter:

```
public class TabsFragmentPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private readonly Fragment[] fragments;
    private readonly string[] titles;

    public TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Dictionary<string, Fragment> fragments) : base(fm)
    {
        this.fragments = fragments.Values.ToArray();
        this.titles = fragments.Keys.ToArray();
    }
    public override int Count => fragments.Length;

    private String GetCharSeuenceFromString(string s)
    {
        return new String(s);
    }

    public override Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        return base.InstantiateItem(container, position);
    }

    public override void SetPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object @object)
    {
        base.SetPrimaryItem(container, position, @object);
    }

    public override Fragment GetItem(int position)
    {
        return fragments[position];
    }

    public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
    {
        return GetCurrentPageTitle(position);
    }

    private ICharSequence GetCurrentPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return GetCharSeuenceFromString(titles[position]);
    }
}
```

Happy codding!

P.S. Don't use fragments with generics.

Comment: That's not how the MVVMCross (and especially 6.2+) works. So I think that this solution is useless.