# Tabs with MVVMCross 6.2+

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, tabs, mvvmcross, android-appcompat

I have created simple Xamarin Android app with MVVMCross 6.2+ and trying to create tab layout properly. Right now I get only one (the last registered tab) on screen, but after rotation (recreation) there are all three of them (as it should be). What's wrong? What have I missed? How to fix it?
Thanks in advance for your help.

## MvvmCrossTabs.Core

### HomeViewModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MvvmCross.Commands;
using MvvmCross.Logging;
using MvvmCross.Navigation;
using MvvmCross.ViewModels;

namespace MvvmCrossTabs.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class HomeViewModel : MvxNavigationViewModel
    {
        public IMvxAsyncCommand ShowInitialViewModelsCommand { get; private set; }

        public HomeViewModel(IMvxLogProvider logProvider, IMvxNavigationService navigationService) : base(logProvider, navigationService)
        {
            ShowInitialViewModelsCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(ShowInitialViewModels);
        }

        private async Task ShowInitialViewModels()
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(new List<Task>
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate<Tab1ViewModel>(),
                NavigationService.Navigate<Tab2ViewModel>(),
                NavigationService.Navigate<Tab3ViewModel>()
            });
        }
    }
}
```

### Tab1ViewModel.cs (Tab2ViewModel.cs, Tab3ViewModel.cs)

```
using MvvmCross.Logging;
using MvvmCross.Navigation;
using MvvmCross.ViewModels;

namespace MvvmCrossTabs.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class Tab1ViewModel : MvxNavigationViewModel
    {
        public Tab1ViewModel(IMvxLogProvider logProvider, IMvxNavigationService navigationService) : base(logProvider, navigationService)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

### App.cs

```
using MvvmCross.IoC;
using MvvmCross.ViewModels;
using MvvmCrossTabs.Core.ViewModels;

namespace MvvmCrossTabs.Core
{
    public class App : MvxApplication
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            CreatableTypes()
                .EndingWith("Service")
                .AsInterfaces()
                .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

            RegisterAppStart<HomeViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

## MvvmCrossTabs.Android

### MainApplication.cs

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat;
using MvvmCrossTabs.Core;

namespace MvvmCrossTabs.Android
{
    [Application]
    public class MainApplication : MvxAppCompatApplication<MvxAppCompatSetup<App>, App>
    {
        public MainApplication() : base() { }

        public MainApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) { }
    }
}
```

### home.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/maincontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### tab1.axml (tab2.axml, tab3.axml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

### styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

### HomeView.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat;
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Presenters.Attributes;
using MvvmCrossTabs.Core.ViewModels;

namespace MvvmCrossTabs.Android
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask, Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    [MvxActivityPresentation]
    public class HomeView : MvxAppCompatActivity<HomeViewModel>
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.home);

            // Replaces Action Bar with new Toolbar.
            var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            ViewModel.ShowInitialViewModelsCommand.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

### Tab1View.cs (Tab2View.cs, Tab3View.cs)

```
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4;
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Binding.BindingContext;
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Presenters.Attributes;
using MvvmCrossTabs.Core.ViewModels;

namespace MvvmCrossTabs.Android.Views
{
    [MvxTabLayoutPresentation(TabLayoutResourceId = Resource.Id.tabs, ViewPagerResourceId = Resource.Id.viewpager, Title = "Tab 1", ActivityHostViewModelType = typeof(HomeViewModel))]
    [Register(nameof(Tab1View))]
    public class Tab1View : MvxFragment<Tab1ViewModel>
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.tab1, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have still no solution. Only a hack calling Recreate() at the end of OnCreate() once. This way it works as I wanted to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone looking for the solution of this problem, at current moment it boils down to having splash screen activity which implements the MvxSplashScreenAppCompatActivity class.

Softlion is working on a PR which will remove this requirement.

You can track current state of the issue here:
[Tabs with MVVMCross 6.2+](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/3357)

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround is to use this piece of code in HomeView:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    var setupSingleton = MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(this);
    setupSingleton.EnsureInitialized();
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    // my code here
}
```

Thanks @kmiterror for the tip.